# What does re.split(r'[_]' , i) does?

Tags: feature-extraction

What does re.split(r'[_]' , i) does?

I have a function with the above code. Can someone please explain how does the split occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and is therefore better suited for the stackoverflow stackexchange page, but the provided code simply splits a string using a regex pattern (`[_]`). The regex pattern used simply finds any underscores (`_`) in the string, as a result the code simply splits the string on underscore characters:

```
import re

text = "test_string"
print(re.split(r'[_]' , text))
# ['test', 'string']
```